# Where can I find a garage door (slot) mail basket?

Tags: garage

I'm looking for a place I can buy a garage door mail slot basket. I had one in my old (rented) house and I'm looking to install one.
It should look something like the image below, and keep upright when the garage door is opening.
[This site](http://www.brighthardware.com/mailcatcher_eb2bl_web.html) was selling them, but as you can see on the top of their page, not anymore :(
If you have a suggestion where I can buy the basket itself (need to have round edge to act as a hinge when the door opens) and assemble it myself, that would be a good start too.

[image]

Comment: They're back in stock at www.brighthardware.com, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [guy](http://toddkeeblersthisnewhouse.blogspot.com/2008/02/netflix-should-thank-me.html) crafted his own.

This site sells [mail baskets](http://houseofantiquehardware.com/s.nl/sc.10/category.48/.f).

You could always use a priority mail box and attach it with a few bolts and screws. Hot glue a dowel rod to the box and use the same type of clips to get the hanging effect.